# c++ unhandled exception 0xC0000005 Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE, cannot find Marshal.cxx

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I made a small test program that reads in commands from a file, sends those commands over a COM port (the problem also occurs when I use Ethernet sockets), and writes the responses to a new file. I am able to go through the file completely, and close the files. If I leave my program open (running through the window loop, not doing anything) I get this exception

```
First-chance exception at 0x7670C99E (ole32.dll) in MyProgram.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE
```

From the call stack I have:

[image]

If I try to continue from the exception, it says "marshal.cxx not found".

I wonder if its a similar problem to this question

[Unhandled exception in marshal.cxx under VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489516/unhandled-exception-in-marshal-cxx-under-vs2013)

I am using `GetOpenFileName()` when I open the command file.

`szFileName` -> command file name
`sFileName` -> log file name

```
void GetFileName(HWND hwnd)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    //char FilterSpec = "All Files(.)\0*.*\0";
    TCHAR *Title = _T("Open....");
    TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szFileTitle[MAX_PATH];

    *szFileName = 0;
    *szFileTitle = 0;
    /* fill in non-variant fields of OPENFILENAME struct. */
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = GetFocus();
    ofn.lpstrFilter = _T("All Files(.)\0*.*\0");
    ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxCustFilter = 0;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = "C://Interface Card/Test Files"; //_T("."); // Initial directory.
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = szFileTitle;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = Title;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = _T(".");
    ofn.Flags = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;

    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
    {
        LoadTextFile(szFileName);
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (szFileName[i] != NULL)
    {
        sFileName[i] = szFileName[i];
        i++;
    }

    //Subtract .txt at end (4)
    i = i - 4;

    sFileName[i] = ' '; i++;

    time_t now = time(0);   //Get current time
    struct tm tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    char bufTime[80];

    strftime(bufTime, sizeof(bufTime), "Date %m-%d-%Y Time %I-%M", &tstruct);

    j = 0;
    while (bufTime[j] != '\0')
    {
        sFileName[i] = bufTime[j];
        i++; j++;
    }

    sFileName[i] = '.'; i++;
    sFileName[i] = 't'; i++;
    sFileName[i] = 'x'; i++;
    sFileName[i] = 't'; i++;
    sFileName[i] = '\0'; i++;
}
```

And I open both files as so:

```
BOOL SaveTextFile(LPCTSTR pszFileName)
{
    FileLog = fopen(pszFileName, "w");
    if (FileLog == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    else
        return TRUE;        
}

BOOL LoadTextFile(LPCTSTR pszFileName)
{
    File = fopen(pszFileName, "r");
    if (File == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    else
        return TRUE;
}
```

My main window loop:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);

    if (isTest)
    {
        RunTest();          
    }
}
```

Looks like there is a hotfix for that problem listed in the previous question, but I want to make sure that this is my actual problem before applying the fix.

Has anyone else seen this problem?

Its pretty hard to debug through this, because I have noticed that sometimes when I am debugging through I never get the exception, maybe because I am changing the timing of events. The exception also happens at random, sometimes a second or two after the test finished, sometimes a minute or more...

I have noticed that the problem occurs while I debug and also in release mode.

Comment: The bit-pattern `0xFEEEFEEE` designates memory, that has been released (see [Win32 Debug CRT Heap Internals](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html)). You are accessing an object, that has been deleted.

Comment: Change `OPENFILENAME ofn;` to `OPENFILENAME ofn = {0};`. See if it helps. As written, some members of the structure contain random garbage.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but changing to OPENFILENAME ofn = {0}; did not help.

Comment: It is a standard sign of heap corruption, it doesn't have anything to do with the code you posted.  The usual problem with diagnosing heap corruption.  The code that dies is an OS component that does something with network interfaces.  Since you save to a directory named "Interface Card", your program presumably pokes at a network interface.  *That* code has a bug.  Don't mess with hot-fixes.  Application Verifier can be helpful to pin-point the evil-doer.

Comment: Having this issue too. Does anyone find a solution?

Comment: I am seeing this too.  It only happens when I call GetOpenFileName, and the crash happens 1 minute (to the minute) after I complete the selection. I do clear the OPENFILENAME structure. There is some major stuff that GetOpenFileName() brings with it, and I'm ready to kick it out of my program..

Comment: UPDATE:  Too soon to tell, maybe, but I have come to believe that a (3rd party) shell extension may be causing this.  I can't claim it for sure, but I had an old install of DropBox which I was not using -- I removed this and now I do not see this crash.  Also, see this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769156/could-a-shell-extension-be-causing-my-program-to-crash